# Which type do I return with AWS lambda responses in typescript to suite AWS APIGateway Method Response?

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I want to build a proper typescript project on AWS lambda.

Right now, I am having the following definitions:

```
export type HttpResponse = {
  statusCode: number;
  headers: {};
  body: string;
}

export async function readCollection (event, context, callback): Promise<HttpResponse>{

  console.log(event); // Contains incoming request data (e.g., query params, headers and more)

  const data =  [
    {
      id: "a7b5bf50-0b5b-11e9-bc65-6bfc39f23288",
      name: "some thing",
      uri: `/notifications/a7b5bf50-0b5b-11e9-bc65-6bfc39f23288`
    }
  ]

  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      status: "ok",
      data: data
     })
  };

  return response;
};
```

**But**

Instead of my custom `HttpResponse` type, I want to use an official definition.

*But which official type do I import and return?*

Comment: I don't think there is an "official" types from AWS, you may find community ones. Also I think that what your looking for is API Gateway definition, as lambda can return whatever you want based on what you do with it.

Comment: True .. IT is more 'api gateway method response type ' ;)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The [@types/aws-lambda package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/aws-lambda) provides types for using TypeScript inside of an AWS Lambda function. For AWS Lambda functions invoked using [API Gateway's Lambda Proxy integration type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format) take the following steps:

Install the package

```
$ yarn add --dev @types/aws-lambda
```

Or if you prefer npm:

```
$ npm i --save-dev @types/aws-lambda
```

Then in your handler file:

```
import { APIGatewayProxyEvent, Context, APIGatewayProxyResult } from "aws-lambda"

export async function hello (event: APIGatewayProxyEvent, context: Context): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> {
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      message: 'Hello world',
      input: event,
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: You can just apply "APIGatewayProxyHandler" to the function and it will inherit the types for event and context.

```/**
 * Works with Lambda Proxy Integration for Rest API or HTTP API integration Payload Format version 1.0
 * @see - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html
 */
export type APIGatewayProxyHandler = Handler<APIGatewayProxyEvent, APIGatewayProxyResult>;```

Comment: [This reply to an issue on @types/aws-lambda](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/46689#issuecomment-673928697) cleared things up for me. Thank you for pointing us in the right direction!

Comment: Here is the official doc that confirms above: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/typescript-handler.html

Answer (score 4):

After days of research I found the answer so close ;)

you return `Promise<APIGateway.MethodResponse>`

```
import { APIGateway } from "aws-sdk";

export async function readCollection (event, context, callback): Promise<APIGateway.MethodResponse> {

  console.log(event); // Contains incoming request data (e.g., query params, headers and more)

  const data =  [
    {
      id: "a7b5bf50-0b5b-11e9-bc65-6bfc39f23288",
      name: "some thing",
      uri: `/notifications/a7b5bf50-0b5b-11e9-bc65-6bfc39f23288`
    }
  ]

  const response = {
    statusCode: "200",
    headers: {
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      status: "ok",
      data: data
     })
  };

  return response;
};
```

Comment: Nice. I have upvoted your answer and removed mine. I have been using Lambda for several years now but couldn't find about this. Great work @wzr1337

Comment: Actually this is incorrect. The "aws-sdk" package is providing types for the AWS Client SDK and is importing the type from https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/74e274612f507f8c00b9a628f293cd8e180da849/clients/apigateway.d.ts#L2842 but this is the API Gateway control plane REST API used to create/modify an actual API in API Gateway as documented at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/method-response/ . See my answer below for an alternative (and correct) way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

The [AWS Lambda types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/aws-lambda) define the handler as:

```
export type Handler<TEvent = any, TResult = any> = (
    event: TEvent,
    context: Context,
    callback: Callback<TResult>,
) => void | Promise<TResult>;
```

So essentially you get to decide what the return type is, thanks to the [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

If you're using other AWS services with the lambda (e.g. API Gateway), you're input and response may be different.

---

*Link to the Handler type: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/aws-lambda/index.d.ts#L1076-L1089*

Answer (score -4):

You need to return a callback otherwise if your lambda was triggered by an s3 put it will think it did not execute and will continue executing your function from time to time generating duplicated calls. You also need to return a callback from an API Gateway request so you can send a proper response to the user.

For success calls:

```
callback(null, response);
```

For error calls:

```
callback(error, null);
```

Comment: The above code works just fine returning a promise.. you do not need the callback

Comment: The question is: whicht Typescript type do I specify as return value of the promise